# Safari 6 images colored incorrectly

Tags: image, safari

I wish I could have a more helpful title for this question, but honestly I have no idea whats going on.

After upgrading to safari 6, some of the images on my site now appear to be lighter shades? This is a weird problem to explain, so I took some screenshots that will hopefully explain the problem better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/te7y7.png

On the left is the screenshot from my site, with the two images by themselves (also in safari).  As you can see, they are noticeably lighter on the site vs by themselves. Now I'm sure you're thinking this has something to do with the images being partially transparent or something, but heres a screenshot from chrome (which looks identical to safari 5.2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/plKxJ.png

Absolutely no difference in color.

These are all standard png-24 images, and like I said everything looked perfectly normal in safari 5.2 and continues to look fine in all other major browsers.
ADDITIONALLY, if I draw these images on a canvas as opposed to using IMG tags, the color difference disappears. I don't have any kind of styling that would do anything to IMG tags, not to mention that the repeated background image for the menu does not share this problem, nor does the background tile.

If you have safari 6 and want to go look at things yourself, my site is impiety.net

Comment: I have opened your site in Chrome and Safari 6, but there's no color difference.
However, I had the exact same problem with Safari 5 a few weeks ago and the color difference disappeared after restarting the browser. :)

Comment: Oh nooo, this is the worst news. Restart safari, my comp, pram/nvram, and emptied the cache and the discoloration is still there.
At least I'm the only one that can see it? hopefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Safari 6. Searching around found reports of cases where repeated background images shows color shift, while non-repeating images keeps right color. In some cases it only happens after a page reload.
Looks too weird to be worked around. Should be fixed by Apple.

http://freewaytalk.net/thread/view/114471

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4146673

Hope it helps.

Comment: ah awesome, thanks for finding those, I tried searching around but I had no idea what to look for. "color shift" was a good call. hopefully this gets patched soon