# Mountain Lion Safari 6 jpeg color rendering issues

Tags: macos, colors, safari, rendering, osx-mountain-lion

My question is similar to this question, which is about PNG file used as repeating backgrounds in Safari 6.

[Safari 6 images colored incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727217/safari-6-images-colored-incorrectly)

However, my question is about JPG image colors shifting when the image is smaller than a certain pixel size.  I hope that somebody has a solid fix, workaround or can point to something documenting this as a known issue.

I have several elements and CSS all with a solid color set to #FF9B0F which match on all browsers except OSX Mountain Lion Safari v6.  **Please note that I am not looking for the colors to match cross-browser.  The issue is that two elements side-by-side in this one version of Safari do not match each other.**  The color of the smaller element renders as something else entirely than its designated HEX code.

I have been pulling my hair out all day.  I started with GIF images for backgrounds and sprites as well as CSS that would not match colors.  As per Apple, Safari, unlike other browsers, uses ICC color profiles.  The recommended solution is to remove the ICC profile from the image file or use sRGB.  I've tried both and these are saved without any ICC profiles.

Anyway, after trying everything I could think of, I noticed that all of the large background images were rendering correctly and the smaller sprites were not rendering correctly.  Through the process of elimination, it all came down to the size (pixel dimensions) and nothing else!  Even by simply zooming in and out of my webpage the colors shifted back and forth.

The larger images render the exact correct HEX color (as per RGB color meter utility) and the smaller versions of the image are rendering as a completely different HEX color.  The two test cases below were created in PhotoShop using all the same settings except for final crop.  They look identical in PhotoShop and only look different in my version of Safari.  You will only see them rendered as two different colors using Safari v6 in Mountain Lion.

After dozens of scenarios and test cases, my final code is simply this...

```
<img src="test-100x100.jpg" />
<img src="test-800x200.jpg" />
```

**test-100x100.jpg: 100 x 100 pixels (#FF9B0F)**
My HEX color meter is reporting this one as #E8A400

[image]

**test-800x200.jpg: 800 x 200 pixels (#FF9B0F)**
My HEX color meter is correctly reporting this one as #FF9B0F

[image]

In your browser, the two images above should appear as the same color.  However, in my browser, Safari 6, I see two very different colors as proven by my HEX color meter utility.

Here's the really weird part, the **ONLY** difference between these two files is their size.

I suspect that there is a bug in this version of Safari that incorrectly applies an ICC color profile even though no such thing is part of the file.  I see two very distinct colors and the color meter proves these colors are different.

---

**EDIT**:

As per Marc's comments, using HTML to swap their sizes...

```
<img src="test-100x100.jpg" width="800" height="200" />
<img src="test-800x200.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

Making the first one larger, it stays the same incorrect color.  Making the second one smaller, it shifts into the incorrect color.

Comment: try displaying the SAME image, and just put the wrong width/height in the html. if the exact same source image is display different, then apple's messing with color balances somewhere up the food chain. e.g. `<img src="foo.jpg" width=100>` and `<img src="foo.jpg" width=800>`

Comment: @MarcB, this is interesting.  When I use the HTML attributes to make the smaller one bigger, the color stays the same.  However, when I make the larger one smaller, the color goes bad.  Using HTML to swap sizes, they both become the same wrong color.